# Evince does not show printers

Tags: printing, evince

I have a problem with evince PDF-document viewer. I have a printer that is well configured with cups, and I can print PDFs from other PDF viewers such as Okular, but not with Evince.
There are simply no printer listed when I want to print with Evince, only "print to a file", or "print with lpr". I can use lpr to print with evince, but I have to type the command with the options I want, which is not very practical.

I'm running Debian Testing (Stretch) with Evince 3.22.1. I tried to delete the files `~/.cups/lpoptions` and `~/.config/evince/print-settings` but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Same on arch after updating arch few days ago.

Answer (score 46):

I had the same issue and I couldn't print any images either with most GTK+ applications.

The latest GTK3 (3.22) requires the package `gtk3-print-backends` for printers to be listed in GTK3 print dialogs.

Installing that package did the trick for me.

I'm running Arch Linux.

Comment: We should tell https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/evince/ to update the deps. How is it possible?

Comment: Of course it is. Should be there between OPTIONAL dependencies in my opinion.

Comment: Unbelievable. Also, great catch!

Comment: I just added a [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/53082) for this. It's a weird "bug" in that technically it's [listed in optional deps](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/gtk3) for `gtk3` and stated on the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#Installation). I still think it warranted a report as it's a unique case where functionality *was* built-in to package A and was then removed, requiring the installation of B. This should be made more obvious to the user.

Comment: Hmmm. So I think I was wrong about the pacman logs, and the message is only captured in the output during an upgrade. Thus, the upgrade may have mentioned the new optional dep in the terminal output but not captured this in the log. The bug was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I started to have such an issue since I set my TMPDIR to point to /run/user/$(id)/ .
It turned out, that apparmor was denying access to evince, with these random problems. So I tuned the evince profile.