# How to select paper source with lpr?

Tags: command-line, printing, cups, lpr

I had trouble printing PDFs with evince (fixed by [Evince does not show printers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319363/evince-does-not-show-printers)) and in the meantime used `lpr` successfully to do things.

I found several options in the man page (`page-ranges`, `number-up`) but none to specify the paper source. In the print dialog I can chose between `Tray 1` and `Multipurpose Feeder`.

Is it possible (and if so, how?) to choose the paper source when printing from the command line with `lpr`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to list the printer options with

```
lpoptions -l
```

(add -p and the name of the printer if it is not the default). You should see lines like

```
InputSlot/Media Source: *Auto Main
```

i.e. lines in the format of  *keyword/longer description: value value ...*, with one of the values having a `*` to show it is the default. The actual keywords and values will depend on your printer. You can supply any of these keywords as an option to `lpr`, setting it to one of the values, eg

```
lpr -o InputSlot=Main ...
```

You can use `lpadmin` with a similar `-o keyword=value` to move the `*` to a new default value.